# What does git log --all do in the context of difference between branches?

Tags: git

I have a commit history as follows:

```
* 7a5841d - (6 hours ago) commit messageA  (master)
| * 1552e99 - (6 hours ago) commit messageB (HEAD -> feature1)
| * 2d4a3bd - (6 hours ago) commit messageC
| * 31513f7 - (6 hours ago) commit messageD
| * 3335afb - (7 hours ago) commit messageE
|/
* 5be4cf7 - (27 hours ago) commit messageF (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| * 870f217 - (27 hours ago) commit messageG (origin/develop)
| * 70f1973 - (27 hours ago) commit messageH
|/
* 50e3bba - (27 hours ago) commit messageI

$ git log --oneline master ^feature1 --no-merges
  7a5841d commit messageA

$ git log --all --oneline master ^feature1 --no-merges
  7a5841d commit messageA
  870f217 commit messageG
  70f1973 commit messageH
```

What does `git log --all` do here? Why does it return the extra two commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the first really is the complete set of all commits (I have no reason to believe it's not, but there could be more that we can't see, e.g., in reflogs—that doesn't affect this answer, but it's a subtle point either way).

What `--all` means is *all references* (plus `HEAD`).  But that's not the whole story here.  (I'm also going to leave out `--no-merges` since there are no merges anyway.)

#### References

Let's start with the notion of *references*, as distinguished from branches, tags, and remote-tracking branches.  A reference is the fully general form: all three of the specific varieties (branch, tag, remote-tracking branch) are a kind of reference.  A branch name like `master` is mostly just a short way of saying the full reference name, `refs/heads/master`.  A tag name like `v1.3` is a short way of saying `refs/tags/v1.3`, and a remote-tracking branch name like `origin/develop` is a short way of saying `refs/remotes/origin/develop`.

There are more possible references: for instance, `stash` is short for `refs/stash`.  If you have an active stash (from `git stash save`), you have a `refs/stash`.  That would have shown up here, and didn't; so you don't have one.  But `--all` would include it, if you did.  There are also optional Git "notes" under `refs/notes`, and there may be more.  Anything that starts with `refs/` is a reference, and the `--all` flag gets them all!  (Plus, as I mentioned, `HEAD`, but usually that doesn't matter.  Note that `HEAD` doesn't start with `refs/` so it's nominally not a *reference*, even though it's the one Git mostly uses by default!)

You can use `--branches` to mean "all branches" (everything in `refs/heads/*`), `--tags` to mean "all tags" (`refs/tags/*`), and `--remotes` to mean "all remote-tracking branches" (`refs/remotes/*`).  Using some or all of these, you can leave out the extra `--all` items, if they exist.

#### Short names like `master`

Almost any time you use a name like `master`, Git goes through the six-step reference lookup process described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Click on the link and find the six-step list, and note that the translation from `master` to `refs/heads/master` is actually step *four*.  If there were a `refs/tags/master`, that happens at step *three* and that's the reference you would get.

(I say *almost* any time here because some commands, such as `git checkout`, try to treat a name as a branch name first, and only later go through the six-step process to resolve the name.  So `git checkout master` checks out the branch, not the tag, if there is both a branch `master` and a tag `master`.  The `git log` command doesn't: if both exist, you get the tag here!  The short version is "don't do that" :-) —never set yourself up with both a branch named *X* and a tag named *X*.  It's too confusing.)

#### Negated references, reachability, and the commit graph

Your final command is:

```
git log --all --oneline master ^feature1 --no-merges
```

You don't need `master` here, because `--all` means *all references*, and `master` means "find a `master` reference" (probably the branch).  It's already been found.

The `^feature1`, however, is crucial.  When Git goes to enumerate all *reachable commits*, it takes into account all the places you told it to start—in this case, `--all` means "all references"—but it overrides these with all the places you told it to *stop*.  A prefix hat `^` negates a reference: it means "put this into the stop list."  Git finds the specific commit that `feature1` names; we can see above that this is `1552e99`.

So Git puts `1552e99` into the "stop" list.  But it doesn't just stop there: it finds all commits *reachable from* `1552e99` (messageB).  That starts with its first and only parent commit, which is `2d4a3bd` (messageC).  Commit `2d4a3bd` has a parent, though: that's commit `31513f7` (messageD); and that has a parent, `3335afb` (messageE), which has parent `5be4cf7` (messageF).

Note, though, that the parent of `5be4cf7` is `50e3bba` (messageI), *skipping past* the other two commits.  (Follow the lines connecting the asterisks in the `git log --graph` output.  This may be easier without `--oneline`, at least at first; it's almost certainly easier in a graphical viewer like `gitk` or some GUI.)

When we get to `50e3bba` we stop: it has no parent at all.  It is a *root commit* (which just means "a commit with no parents").  So that finishes up our list of "stop" commits.

Now `git log --all` can go on to look at all references.  There are a total of four: `master`, `feature1`, `origin/master`, and `origin/develop`.  (Or maybe there are five or six: we should also consider `HEAD` and `origin/HEAD`.  However, those last two are *symbolic* references, as in, they just name other existing references.  So they get folded in and we're back down to just four.)

Those four names resolve to commits `7a5841d` (`master`), `1552e99` (`HEAD -> feature1`), `5be4cf7` (`origin/master, origin/HEAD`), and `870f217` (`origin/develop`).  So `git log` puts—or tries to put—those four commits into the list of things to show you.

`1552e99`, however, is in the stop list.  So Git doesn't show it; it ejects it from the "to be shown" list (or never puts it in there in the first place, which has the same effect).  Git picks one of the three remaining commits and shows it.  We can see that it picked `7a5841d`.<sup>1</sup>

Git tries to add `7a5841d`'s parent commit(s) to the "show list", but `7a5841d`'s parent is `5be4cf7`.  That's already in the "stop" list, through `^feature1`.  It either gets thrown out or never makes it in.

That leaves just `870f217` in the show list.  Git shows it next, and then adds its parents to the show list.  It has just one parent, `70f1973`.  So that's now in the show list; Git shows you that one.  Git tries to add *its* parent to the show list, but that's `50e3bba`, which is in the stop list.

The show list is now empty, so `git log` is finished.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's another tricky point here.  When Git is in this position of picking one commit from an otherwise un-sorted pile of possible commits, it takes the one with the *numerically biggest commit date*.  If you make a commit that's dated far into the future, put it on a branch or tag so that it's reachable from `--all`, and run `git log --all`, that future commit comes out first every time.